# re-plotting of data on same GUI axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am working with GUI in matlab and I have one axes to plot the data. I want to keep track what I have already plotted in order to re-plot it if needed on same axes and for this purpose, I have list box which holds names of data sets which I have plotted. I am trying to find appropriate way to select the name of data set in list box and re-plot the data set on axes. I am setting some properties of axes while plotting, so I do not not want to perform the re-plotting operation, instead, I want re-use the handle (of some kind) to get the plot data again.

I have some experience of using figure handle to get figure by providing its handle but I am looking something similar for plotting in axes.

```
f1  = figure 
plot ([0:0.1:2*pi] , cos ([0:0.1:2*pi]))
f2  = figure 
plot ([0:0.1:2*pi] , sin([0:0.1:2*pi]))

figure(f1) or figure (f2)
```

Comment: Please try to separate the problem you're trying to solve (i.e. tying a plotted line to a listbox/dropdown/popupmenu item), from the solution you think is best and why it doesn't work (i.e. something about names of datasets and handles). It only makes it difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: Actually, I want to reuse the handles of plots to re-draw them on same axes depend upon the selection from list. If I have handle of plot like  h = plot ([1:0,1:2*pi], sin([1:0,1:2*pi])) and I have one axes on GUI and how to use this handle to get back the plot on GUI axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example on how you can do this with 3 plots (save this code as a file and run):

```
function Example
%% // Init
close all;
%% // Example figure
figure(201);
h(1) = ezplot('sin(x)'); hold on; h(2) = ezplot('cos(x)'); h(3) = ezplot('tan(x)');

%% // Create a UI control
hDrop = uicontrol(201,...
    'FontUnits',get(0,'defaultuicontrolFontUnits'),...
    'Style','popupmenu',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.729,0.879,0.134,0.027],...
    'Callback',@dropdown_callback,...
    'String',{'Plot1';'Plot2';'Plot3'},...
    'Value',1); %// default plot

handles = struct('hPlots',h,'hDrop',hDrop); %// Create a "handles" structure
guidata(201,handles); %// Associate the handles structure with the figure
hide_all_besides_selected(1); %// Unhide only the default

function dropdown_callback(hObj,~)
    hide_all_besides_selected(get(hObj,'Value'));

function hide_all_besides_selected(selectedVal)
    handles = guidata(gcf); %// Retrieve the handles
    for ind1=1:numel(handles.hPlots) %// Hide everything
        set(handles.hPlots,'Visible','off');
    end
    set(handles.hPlots(selectedVal),'Visible','on'); %// Unhide the relevant plot
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, I have to alter few things. However this is the answer which I am searching for.